# How to improve flags in function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code. I dislike this only aesthetically:

```
   public createDocument() {
        try {
            if (this.isOpenDialog) throw 'Dialog already opened!';
            this.loading = true;
            this.isOpenDialog = true;
            this.documentService.loadDocuments(this.application.reglamentid).then((response) => {
                this.documentService.setTypeDocuments(response.typedocuments);
                this.loading = false;
                this.documentDialogFormService.open({ title: 'Документ', application: this.application }).subscribe(() => {
                    this.isOpenDialog = false;
                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
        }
    }
```

As you can see there are two flags:  `this.loading` and `this.isOpenDialog`. First controls opening dialog, The second indicates loading.

Is it possible somehow to improve it?

Comment: How would you think it would need to be improved?

Comment: Join two varaibles to one

Comment: Why? They control different things.

Comment: You could make it states with enums. But not sure how much of an improvement that is. You are trying to combine two things that mean different things.

Comment: "I dislike this only aesthetically" Then you're asking for others' opinions based on aesthetics rather than facts or experience, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you please add the code which uses `this.loading`? This would help get the complete picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you have is typically what people use since it is two distinct states for two different things. Reason why is the dialog could be loading and be shown at the same time. That means both could be true. Depending on what you do with it might make this the optimal solution.

If you want you could have one state  that holds both. It might seem cleaner, but as you can see the check to see if it is opened is a bit more confusing since it has to check two states.

```
enum ModalStates {
  Closed,
  Loading,
  Opened
}

public createDocument() {
  try {
    if (this.modalState === ModalStates.Loading || this.modalState === ModalStates.Opened ) throw 'Dialog already opened!';
    this.modalState = ModalStates.Loading;
    this.documentService.loadDocuments(this.application.reglamentid).then((response) => {
      this.documentService.setTypeDocuments(response.typedocuments);
      this.modalState = ModalStates.Opened
      this.documentDialogFormService.open({
        title: 'Документ',
        application: this.application
      }).subscribe(() => {
        this.modalState = ModalStates.Closed
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
  }
}
```